# Getting Started with the WeChat Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, wechat

I have downloaded the SDK example from WeChat website: http://dev.wechat.com/document/gettingstart/android/

I used Eclipse and ADT, target platform Android 2.2 on Samsung Galaxy Spica i5700.

The problem is that the provided demo application is only capable of starting WeChat messenger, while all other function calls do not make any effect on WeChat app.

I was debugging through Eclipse and I saw that API calls to WeChat return success, but weChat is not really responding to any request from the demo app. For example, if I want to share text on "Moments" or to send an image to current scene (chat session), nothing happens, but also no error occurs.

Has anyone made it work this demo application?

Thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/21915888/tutorial-of-integrating-wechat-app-in-android-app

Answer (score 6):

It's work for me after I add debug keystore:
Add wechat's debug key (found in the package root folder) into ( Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom debug keystore ) 
then clean and build again

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Mange to solve it using the following step:

1. Re-add the libammsdk.jar
2. Add proguard.cfg with

   -keep class com.tencent.mm.sdk.openapi.WXMediaMessage { *;}

   -keep class com.tencent.mm.sdk.openapi.** implements com.tencent.mm.sdk.openapi.WXMediaMessage$IMediaObject {*;}
3. Add wechat's debug key (found in the package root folder) into ( Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom debug keystore )
4. You might need to clean and build or even restart Eclipse.
5. (Optional) Run the Application, click on send message (跳转到发消息界面) follow by get token (获取微信访问Token)

Hope that this will help. :)

*****Do not remove the debug key at the Custom debug keystore after installing the wechat demo application to the phone as other application will not work due to different signature.**

Comment: Between step 4 and step 5, you should click on login (the first button, on the first page with "XXappXXXXX" X being some chinese characters)
Then Wait for a couple a seconds before doing step 5

Comment: can anyone, please let me know shere can i find the wechat's debug key?

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm trying to do same thing.

Take a look to these links (i found the first one when i accidentally clicked "Share on Moments" - 
"Getting Started - iOS" on page http://dev.wechat.com/document/, yeah, it's highly illogical):

http://dev.wechat.com/document/gettingstart/timeline/

http://dev.wechat.com/document/api/timeline/

It seems that api described there can be used everywhere, not only on iOS, cause this is just http-requests.

Hope it'll help you and me :-)

Comment: Links have changed, can you share some code on how to use this http api ?

Comment: cant find any http based api :(