# Post Moments with Wechat API on Android

Tags: android, api, wechat

I created an app with the Wechat API. I try to post on my user's wall.
I can publish on Wechat moments successfully on iOS (with the notice saying the app was not approved yet). However on Android, nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
  private IWXAPI api;

  api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, Constants.WECHAT_APP_ID);
  api.registerApp(Constants.WECHAT_APP_ID);

  String text = "Post on Wechat Wall";
  WXTextObject textObj = new WXTextObject();
  textObj.text = text;

  WXMediaMessage msg = new WXMediaMessage();
  msg.mediaObject = textObj;
  msg.description = text;
  boolean isChecked = false; // true

  SendMessageToWX.Req req = new SendMessageToWX.Req();
  req.transaction = buildTransaction("text"); 
  req.message = msg;
  req.scene = isChecked ? SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneTimeline : SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneSession;

  api.sendReq(req);
  finish();
```

ps : Wechat didn't approve the app yet (submitted it 1 month ago). Could it be one of the reason?

Comment: You mean approved in the appstore/playstore, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento The app is already approved in the app stores. But not approved by Wechat/Tencent. The app need to be approved by them for X or Y reasons (make disappear the "app not yet verified" for example). But I also think it needs to be approved to be able to published stories on the android app?

Comment: then your problem is not with PlayStore, but with the connection to the API of WeChat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't my code, but the platform where I submitted it.

I submitted to [dev.wechat.com](http://dev.wechat.com/) (english version of the developer platform), even if the docs looks/ up to date, the SDK for iOS and Android are not. And your submission will never be reviewed (5 months after the submissions still no sign of activity).

Solution :

Create an account on the Chinese version of the developer platform ([open.weixin.qq.com](https://open.weixin.qq.com/), then submit your app on it. It's exactly the same fields and order as the english platform.
Google translate will be your best friend here.

I got my application approved after 3 business days.

Comment: Im attempting to do what you suggest, but at some point it requests for a cell phone number so you can receive a confirmation code. It is not accepting my US number (Im assuming it's expecting a Chinese number ) and also the address asumes that you are on China. How did you bypass that?

Comment: This did not work for me. It requires a Chinese phone number to verify and will not accept US phone number and will not allow you to skip phone verification.

Comment: Really? Need to register our app on wechat website to add a button to share content to wechat moment?

Answer (score 1):

After Searching a lot finally got answer
as Eric suggest login to weixin.qq.com site

here you need to submit 2 things, application package name and signature,
signature is not any sha1 or md 5

download we chat apk from this link and generate signature from this apk, and submit on site.

https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=open1419319167&token=&lang=zh_CN