# wechat android app api not Working

Tags: android, wechat

I m facing problem using wechat android apis.
 We chat android apis are not working in my app.
I registered my app in app registration page but,
 I haven't yet put the signature of the application in the registration page. Please someone let me know how to get the signature of the application from debug.keystore so that the app gets approved.

Comment: Please elaborate on what the problem specifically is. "Android apis not working" is not very helpful. In the mean time please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284733/wechat-android-api

Comment: I have an android app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diankeda.huaquanquan) and uses Wechat Login. It only works with release signed apk. So when I want to test wechat features I only test it with release signed apk, and test other features with unsigned apk.