# problems when registering app for WeChat API

Tags: wechat

I am trying WeChat API in android.

I couldn't send text from my app to WeChat, and I found below.
[WeChat android api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284733/wechat-android-api)

So I made signature, but I am failing to approve my app in site (http://dev.wechat.com/app/list/).

Problem is, that I can not upload icons.

I made two icons: 24bit png 28*28 gray-scale for watermark, and 24bit png 108*108 for high resolution, just as the register form guided.

However, when I try to upload each icons, I can see red error message, 'Unable to set the icon'.
That is not the problem of file size or file format, because I can see other messages if I change size or file format of my icon files.

Anyone can share your experiences?
Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried so many icons, none of them work. Have you solved yours?

Comment: @JSNoob No.. If I find the way, I will leave comment. You too please....

Comment: @JSNoob , anyone found solution ? I've the same issue here ! !

Comment: i have the same issue!!!

Comment: Suggest you guys to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629147/wechat-api-is-unable-to-set-app-icon

Comment: Any one got solution to above issue?