# Wechat Api is unable to set app icon

Tags: ios, wechat

I've been trying so hard to upload icon image of watermark and high resolution into Wechat api while registering an app for iOS and here is whats happening:

Check the website here:
http://developers.wechat.com/

I tried different ways to upload 28*28 png transparent or not and grayscale, its really annoying, its not going anywhere and plus the Wechat support they are so not responding.and the high resolution icon is having the same issue.

The error is always : `Unable to set the icon` therefor my app cannot be verified.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently discovered that the english website for Wechat api and app creation is having a bug. Well the only way was to visit : https://open.weixin.qq.com/ which is the Chinese version of Wechat api.

Its easy to use Google Chrome to translate each page from Chinese to English, and the app will be reviewed and then they will give you an app id to use it, and no more problems with uploading the icons.

**Note :** You should have a chinese phone number to activate your account, try to buy a Skype Chinese number if possible.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you, 
Can You Please Tell Me Where You Found "english website for Wechat api and app creation is having a bug", i need to show official Link For Reference

Comment: @Theorist , the website is here : http://developers.wechat.com/ , create an account and try to create an app and you'll face the issue !

Comment: @Aaoli i try many times and face same issue, need some official data for display in reference."why i am not using this site?"

thank you

Comment: @Theorist are you trying to report it to wechat ? The issue is when you create an app , you cannot set icon image in anyway and it shows you this error : unable to set the icon ! Thus the app cannot be verified and cannot be used officially ! Is that what your asking for ?

Comment: @Aaoli hello i use qq.com and get login in we chat and get user details, now i am facing problem with getting friend list of user, i don't have idea how to do this, please help me if you can 
thank you

Comment: @Theorist , Are you asking about getting friends list from Wechat API ? Is that what your asking for ?

Comment: @Theorist I don't have an idea right now , I'm just using my mobile ! I'll check their api tomorrow !!

Comment: @Theorist, As the Wechat api you can only get message or launch or send message or show message ! Seems that the API doesn't allow to get friends list . For reference : http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/documentation ! :)

Comment: @Aaoli in doc NO API for geting Friend List. and i got one sdk from github ( https://github.com/CoolBee-Studio/CoolBee-Studio.github.io/blob/master/EN/router/wx.md ) i use his wxfriends_profile API with my appid but error come invalid AppID
any idea about this?

Comment: @Theorist , have you registered your app in Wechat APIs ? And got the app id they provided you with ? Or your just using the one from the sample ?

Comment: @Aaoli yes i register my app, app id is ok , i authenticate user on we chat and get user baisc info back from we chat.so APPid Is ok. i want to know this msdktest will work as therdparty for me to get friend list ? it's shows friend list on wxfriends_profile API response in above url

Comment: @Theorist since you are getting app Id error ,are you sending the right appid in the url ? Like point 3.3.1.4 ? You should have app id and open id to gain access !

Comment: @Aaoli can i use wechat Appid in msdktest API ?
wechat id is correct and work in wechat API . question is how call API of msdktest using wechat Appid   ?

Comment: @Theorist since you are trying to access everything from the web then here is an official guide : http://admin.wechat.com/wiki that should guide you to get everything work fine hopefully!