# Authenticate mobile application with WeChat

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, wechat

I have an app that provides initial login (authentication) with facebook or twitter.
I would like to add WeChat authentication.
App isn't on the stores yet.

Does anyone have any experience on this kind of authentication?
What are the steps to achieve it?

I'm so confused by wechat documentation because seems have two versions:

- one used to send messages;
- another one, seems, that grants authenticated [API](https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=open1419317851&token=&lang=zh_CN) (chinese documentation only?);

I think that a guide on SO is missing and can help a lot of people considering that documentation is not too clear.

Problem is that I cannot register my app:

- if I use '[developers.wechat.com](http://developers.wechat.com)' I can't create app because of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629147/wechat-api-is-unable-to-set-app-icon).
- if I use 'https://open.weixin.qq.com/' I can't create my account because a chinese phone number is required.

  So?

Comment: start at this https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/frame?t=home/app_tmpl&lang=zh_CN with help of google translation.

Comment: Hi Jiang, thanks for link. Trying to login I stopped at third step "phone number format is not legitimate". Is this valid for European users?

Comment: you cannot register until you own a chinese phone number. You need to buy a chinese number online for this purpose.