# Sharing on WeChat using Wechat sdk in android

Tags: android, wechat

Hi I want to share image to WeChat from my app using Wechat SDK. I have downloaded [this](http://developers.wechat.com/download/sdk/WeChat_SDK_sample_android_en.zip) sample, but it is not working. I have also followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565479/getting-started-with-the-wechat-android-sdk) to add `debug keystore`.The scenario is as follwos:- If user is not logged-in in WeChat app then the sample app open login page in Wechat App but after login nothing is happens. If user is logged- in then nothing is happening. I am using same app id which is working in iOS, so I don't thing there is any problem in app registration. Please help me If any one have done sharing on WeChat. Here is my code

//In OnCreate I have write

```
    api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, Constants.WECHAT_APPID);
    weChatHandler = new WechatHandler(); //WechatHandler is imlemented by  WXAPIEventHandler
    api.handleIntent(getIntent(), weChatHandler);
```

// sharing code

```
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abt_image);

            //Init a WXImageObject object
            WXImageObject imgObj = new WXImageObject(bmp);
            Bit

            WXMediaMessage msg = new WXMediaMessage();
            msg.mediaObject = imgObj;
            Bitmap thumbBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 50, 50, true);
            bmp.recycle();
            msg.thumbData = Utils.bmpToByteArray(thumbBmp, true); //set the thumbnail
            SendMessageToWX.Req req = new SendMessageToWX.Req();
            req.transaction = buildTransaction("img");
            req.message = msg;
            req.scene = SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneSession;
            api.sendReq(req);
```

Comment: my image sharing code is same,if you have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first of all,you must make sure that the thumbData should be within 32KB

> NOTE: The file size should be within 32KB.

You can check it out yourself [wechat document](https://open.weixin.qq.com/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/document/sdk/android/com/tencent/mm/sdk/modelmsg/WXMediaMessage.html)